# How to add a website link to an item in a beamer class document?

Tags: beamer, hyperref, hyperlink

I have a beamer document and this is an example of the code that generates the frame:

```latex
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Some title}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Some random text in the bullet point \hyperlink{website address}{website name}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

That results in an error. So I tried using the the hyperref package as in an article class document, changed the \hyperlink to \href, but I get the same mistake. I want to get a clickable link within the \item text.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\href{<url>}{<site description>}`

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usetheme{default}
\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Some title}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Some random text in the bullet point \href{https://stackexchange.com/}{The StackExchange}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I thought the href command needed the hyperref package, silly me. By the way, It also seems that special characters like #, can't go inside the url unless you also use the \ before them. I forgot that rule.